# Compile multiple modules in separate files into one obj file in Intel Fortran ifort in Windows 7

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I used to do, in one file called `umat.f90`,

```
!!! umat.f90
module1
!! Content of module1
end module1


module2
!! Content of module2
end module2


!! This has to be a subroutine to interface with some legacy code in a software called ABAQUS
subroutine umat (argument-list)
use module1
use module2
!! Content of umat
end subroutine umat
```

This works. I can use `ifort -c umat.f90`, then it generates a `umat.obj` to link to a software called `ABAQUS` (which I can't modify). Now, because `module1` and `module2` may be re-used, I want to save them in separate `.f90` files to comply to the DRY principle. So, this becomes three separate files:

File #1:

```
!!! module1.f90
module1
!! Content of module1
end module1
```

File #2:

```
!!! module2.f90
module2
!! Content of module2
end module2
```

File #3:

```
!!! umat.f90
!! This has to be a subroutine to interface with some legacy code in a software called ABAQUS
subroutine umat (argument-list)
use module1
use module2
!! Content of umat
end subroutine umat
```

However, now if I run `ifort /c module1.f90 module2.f90 umat.f90`, it will generate 3 obj files. The `umat.obj` does not seem to contain the module information from `module1` and `module2` anymore.

Given that I can only provide one `.obj` file to interface with ABAQUS, can I compile them into one big `.obj` file?

PS: I know that I can use python script to copy & paste three files into one automatically every time, but that seems to be a really dirty and inelegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I read the ifort documentation, and the `/Qipo[n]` option might work.  From [this](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-FEF23B3B-D0F6-484F-8DC5-9AB1315A6431.htm):

> /Qipo[n]
>       This option enables interprocedural optimization between files. *n* Is an optional integer that specifies the number of object files the compiler should create. The   integer must be greater than or equal to 0.  If n is greater than 0, the compiler generates n object files, unless n exceeds the number of source files (m), in which case the compiler generates only m object files.

For example:  `ifort /Qipo[1] /c module1.f90 module2.f90 umat.f90`

Hope it works!

Comment: what about Qipo-c (a single command), i.e. ifort /Qipo-c  module1.f90 module2.f90 umat.f90?